# Implement recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've created a recyclerView into a fragment. Everything goes well but when i scroll in the list of elements, the attributes change without reason

Here is the code of the fragment:

```
public class HistorySectionFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = HistorySectionFragment.class.getSimpleName();
static ArrayList<String> a;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);

    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return recyclerView;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    static TextView card_title;
    static TextView card_text;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false));
        card_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
        card_text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
    }
}

public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{
    // Set numbers of Card in RecyclerView.
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final String name = MainActivity.getTestByPosition(position).getName();
        holder.card_title.setText(name);
        final String description = MainActivity.getTestByPosition(position).getDescription();
        holder.card_text.setText(description);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return MainActivity.getSize();
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when the recyclerview calls to create new elements.

EDIT:

When i say the attributes change i mean the information of each cardView change doing scroll

Comment: what for you inflate recycler in code instead of having it in fragment's layout XML? What for both recycler and VH are static classes?

Comment: what do u mean by attributes change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

The problem was in the recycler and in the viewHolder are both Static classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the views in your RecyclerView are not stable. When the views get recycled, the ids are being saved and the data is mismatched.

Trying doing this.

`recyclerView.setHasStableIds(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why you use inflater for the recyclerview? the best way is to declare your recyclerview in xml file and get the recyclerview via findviewById.
Secondly, what do you mean about the attributes change without reason
And finally:it's not very appreciate to use viewholder and adapter like that,

http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example